# Convert uploaded images from various formats to JPEG

Tags: java, image-processing, jai

I am developing a website that allows the user to upload images. I would like to be able to accept BMP, GIF, JPEG and PNG (and maybe one or two others like TIFF) formats. I am using the Apache Commons FileUpload library to achieve this. In order that all the images end up in the same format, I would like to convert all image formats to JPEG format.

What is the easiest way to do this which will work will all of the above image formats?

I have tried:

- ImageIO.read(), which gave `javax.imageio.IIOException: Unexpected block type 0!` for some GIF files and `java.awt.color.CMMException: Invalid image format` for JPEG files.
- JAI, which gave a humongous error trace for GIF files.

**Edit:** Information about the JAI method:

**Stack trace:**

> Error: One factory fails for the operation "gif"
>
> Occurs in: javax.media.jai.ThreadSafeOperationRegistry

followed by literally hundreds of lines of trace.

**Code:**

```
public static void convertToJPG(String originalFile, String newFile) throws Exception {
    RenderedImage image = JAI.create("fileload", originalFile);
    JAI.create("filestore", image, newFile, "JPEG");
}
```

**Image:**

[image: An image which doesn't work.]

Comment: JAI can handle decoding of GIF files, can you share some GIF files or show us some of your code and at least the top of the error trace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), and the convert command, in particular.

Comment: I've had a look, but it looks rather complicated to get running with Java and I can't really see much documentation or examples.

Comment: Just grab a Runtime and then exec the command and arguments.  If you wrap this up in a little class to abstract the details, then you can replace the actual converter at a later time.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with how to do this, would you be able to provide a short code snippet as an example?